# What is the "sock of the valley"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the "sock of the valley" in the following sentences?

> I moved deep into the **sock of the valley**--the only visible human. Except for a ribbon of yellow-lined asphalt below me, there was no sign of human making. Beyond the last hills lay the Pacific.

This is in [this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=tSYPVAqJ548C&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=%22I+moved+deep+into+the+sock+of+the+valley%22&source=bl&ots=wHpnCYSJl_&sig=ClmQ9pfr4yuYjdHK9H2arFnaMCE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwgf349ZPKAhWHn5QKHUm6AbAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22I%20moved%20deep%20into%20the%20sock%20of%20the%20valley%22&f=false).

Comment: I've never heard that expression before, and I [couldn't find it on Google](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=%22sock+of+the+valley%22), either. I wonder if it means "the lower part of the valley," since a sock covers the foot, and "foot of the valley" is a [common expression](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=%22foot+of+the+valley%22). But that's just a conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the understanding is - "explore the valley beyond normal reach".

In general you can you change the expression saying "move deep into the sock of ". This would mean that you are exploring deeper into the matter beyond normal reach.